# EC2 Instance call from lamda function

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

hello I want to call a api which is hoisted in Apache server on AWS EC2 server from my lambda function.

I have configured **VPC** for my lambda function according to my EC2 server instance with same security groups and same zone ,but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your situation is:

- You want to make an HTTP/S API call from an AWS Lambda function to an Amazon EC2 instance
- The Lambda function has been configured to connect to the same VPC as the EC2 instance
- The Lambda function is reporting that it is unable to connect to the EC2 instance

I would recommend:

- Create a Security Group (let's call it `Lambda-SG`) in the same VPC. It does not need any rules.
- Configured the Lambda function to use the Security Group (in the Network section)
- Create another Security Group (let's call it `EC2-SG`) and associate it with the EC2 instance. Add a rule that permits inbound access on the desired port, with the **source set to ID of `Lambda-SG`**.

That is the `EC2-SG` is saying that it will accept inbound connects from `Lambda-SG` on the desired port.

Merely putting resources in the *same* security group does not necessarily mean they can communicate. There needs to be a specific rule that permits the inbound access. The above method is the best way to do so.